# Замена значения по словарю при SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Пытался гуглить, но так и не смог ничего найти.

Вообщем есть таблица logs:

```
id (INTEGER(10)) | action (SET(login, logout, error))
-----------------------------------------------------
 1               | login
 2               | error
 3               | error
 4               | logout
```

При выборке мне нужно преобразовать все значения в action в человекопонятный вид, в соответствии со словарем:

```
login => 'Авторизация'
logout => 'Выход'
error => 'Ошибка'
```

т.е. результат должен быть таким:

```
id | action
------------
 1 | Авторизация
 2 | Ошибка
 3 | Ошибка
 4 | Выход
```

Как подобное можно реализовать средствами MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать через `case`:

```
select id,
       case action when 'login' then 'Авторизация'
                   when 'logout' then 'Выход'
                   when 'error' then 'Ошибка'
       end
  from logs
```

Или использовать join и таблицу значений прямо в запросе:

```
select L.id, N.name
  from logs L
  join (
        select 'login' as action, 'Авторизация' as name
         union all select 'logout','Выход'
         union all select 'error','Ошибка'
       ) N
     on L.action=N.action
```

Но на будущее лучше завести в БД отдельную таблицу - справочник действий, с такой структурой как в выборке `N` в запросе выше. И выполнять в запросе join с этой таблицей. Это позволит избежать необходимости модификации кода при добавлении новых значений action.

Answer (score 2):

Два варианта:

- Если "словарь" большой, занести его в отдельную таблицу и результат получать как `JOIN` с этой таблицей
- Если "словарь" в 5-10 строк, можно использовать `SELECT CASE...`

[Пример тут](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a93be/3)

Comment: Нет не большой, будет всего 2-5 строк

Comment: А функции в mysql никакой нету для этих целей?

Comment: Добавил пример в свой ответ - там онлайн выполнение

Comment: а потом лезть в код CASE, чтобы поменять эти значения)) отдельная таблица или конфиг файл лучше, как по мне.